# Node library for Sequelize audit trail

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js, audit-tables

Is there a proper Node library to enable audit tables with the Sequelize ORM (Postgresql under the hood)?

I found the NPM packages `sequelize-temporal`, `sequelize-paper-trail` and `audit.sequelize`, but they are either very old, don't provide an easy way to migrate an existing DB, or simply don't seem to work.

Or is there another convenient way of keeping track of DB changes that I should know?

Comment: did you you ever find a solution for this?

Comment: @AndreM unfortunately not

Comment: I am also in the same situation . Any luck @AndreM ?

Comment: I did not find one. Ended up just coding something of my own, which I can't share since was for internal use.

Answer (score 1):

This is an old question, but maybe `sequelize-version` could be helpful for you
https://github.com/ivmarcos/sequelize-version